# Hibernate: Unable to load class

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_quick_guide.htm

I'm following the hibernate guide and i'm getting this error someone knows why?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grab the mysql connector jar from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and add it to your classpath.  Perhaps your `/lib` folder

If you are using maven, try including

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

In your pom.xml

Comment: I'm using maven project to do it, which folder i have to put in?